# Changing a user's e-mail address in PWA notifications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, email, project-server, pwa

I have a SharePoint 2016 Server Enterprise with Project Server.
For the SharePoint Server, outgoing e-mail is configured to send as sharepoint@publicdomain.de, which is working like a charm.

However, I have configured a Project Web App, which is configured to send notifications for the users if they set up alerts. Now, one user is shown the wrong e-mail address when changing her notification options. PWA shows the e-mail address as username@internaldomain.local instead of familyname@publicdomain.de. Unfortunately, the user cannot change her e-mail address and instead is told to ask the server admin. Now, I am the admin but don't know where to change the e-mail address.

I have checked the Active Directory server and the Exchange server and the primary e-mail address is correctly set. Also, in SharePoint's User Profile Service, the user profile is imported correctly and the e-mail address is also correct.

What am I doing wrong? Where can I change the user's e-mail address?

Comment: do you use SharePoint permission mode or project permission mode?

Comment: @M.Qassas sorry for the late answer. I'm using SharePoint permission mode.